# Google Autofill address into a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, google-maps

I have found numerous autofill address code, but I wanted to get a Post function added to it so I can post the found data to a PHP page.

Could someone help with the javascript or HTML code to achieve this?

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto-Complete Address Form</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    .container {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="auto-complete.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <div id="address">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">City</label>
                        <input class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        <label class="control-label">State</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Note Add Your API Key Below -->
<!-- The Form Will Not Work Without a Registered API Key -->
<!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key -->

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The following is the Javascript for getting the auto address locations from the Google API.

Javascript

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
```

All I need is to find out how to add a Form Post into this and send it to a PHP page for standard $_POST['field'] gathering of Data?

Answer (score 1):

you can send data by using ajax into your form.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto-Complete Address Form</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    .container {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="auto-complete.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Address</h3>
        </div>
<form method="post">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
            <br>
            <div id="address">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">City</label>
                        <input class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        <label class="control-label">State</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
                     </div>
<button onclick="SendData()">Send</button>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Note Add Your API Key Below -->
<!-- The Form Will Not Work Without a Registered API Key -->
<!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key -->

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Java Script:

```
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
          var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
          };
    function SendData() { 
      $.ajax({
        url: "yourfile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: componentForm,

        success: function(){ // trigger when request was successfull
        window.location.href = 'somewhere'
        },
    error: anyFunction // when error happened
        complete: otherFunction // when request is completed -no matter if the error or not
        // callbacks are of course not mandatory
        })
};
      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: This did not send the info through to the other site. Sorry.